# Calculate height of Xib file

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4, nib

I am implementing 2 `Xib` in my table view.
One of the xib has stack view in it and has dynamic data because of which size can vary from 300 points to 360 points,
Currently, I am implementing the following function.
But this doesn't solve the problem as I have to add max height.
Is there any way I can dynamically calculate the height of my `1 xib` view and update the first cell accordingly

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 360.0 // max height of first xib
    } else {
        return (heightOfSecondXib)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do ***not*** implement `heightForRowAt`. If you have your constraints set up correctly in the `xib` the height will be automatically handled for you by auto-layout.

Comment: I tried that but it's not resizing automatically.

Comment: Then it sounds like you have your constraints setup incorrectly. Show the design of your `XIB` file(s) (screen-capture with the constraints visible).

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic height in `UITableView` use this

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
 }
```

For any dynamic data/sizing problem use UITableViewAutomaticDimension is a good way. But for this, you have to make constraints on Xib accurate so it will show as you want.

Comment: It is correct to say the OP should use proper constraints for automatic cell heights, but you should ***NOT*** implement `heightForRowAt` this way. As of iOS 10 (maybe even 9), `UITableView.automaticDimension` is the default. Implementing it this way forces UIKIt to call this function when it doesn't need to.